# Algorithmic Performance: Solution Analysis of JS Functions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, html5-canvas

Good Day!  I'm shaky on algorithmic performance analysis (Big O time and space complexity) and was wondering if the code I wrote has the proper time and space complexity.  Also are there any ways to improve the complexity?

Below are two functions.  The first takes an array of arrays and runs two `forEach` array helper methods.  Its purpose is to move lines on a screen properly.  The second is a

Function 1 - Time Complexity - O(N^2), Space Complexity - O(N)...is this correct?

```
self.penciledLines.forEach((arr, index) => {
          arr.forEach((line) => {
            if (index === self.selectedArrayLinesIndex) {
              if (
                line.x1 + xDiff <= 0
                || line.y1 + yDiff <= 0
                || line.x1 + xDiff >= 800
                || line.y1 + yDiff >= 600
                || (line.x2 + xDiff <= 0
                  || line.y2 + yDiff <= 0
                  || line.x2 + xDiff >= 800
                  || line.y2 + yDiff >= 600)
              ) {
                const alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
                if (alerted !== 'yes') {
                  alert("On No! You can't move beyond the drawing canvas");
                  localStorage.setItem('alerted', 'yes');
                }
                setTimeout(() => {
                  localStorage.removeItem('alerted');
                }, 1000);
                self.mouseIsDown = false;
                return;
              }
              line.move(xDiff, yDiff);
              self.pos = [mouseX, mouseY];
            }
          });
        });
```

Function2 - Time Complexity - O(N^2), Space Complexity - O(N)...is this correct?  Time is determined by the `forEach` loop within the other `forEach`?

```
let minSquareDistance = null;
          let closestIndex = null;

          self.lines.forEach((line, index) => {
            const squareDistance = line.squareDistanceFrom(x, y);
            if (index === 0 || squareDistance < minSquareDistance) {
              minSquareDistance = squareDistance;
              closestIndex = index;
            }
          });

          let mainArrayIndex; let
            subArrayIndex;
          self.penciledLines.forEach((arr, mainIndex) => {
            arr.forEach((line, subIndex) => {
              const squareDistance = line.squareDistanceFrom(x, y);
              if (squareDistance < minSquareDistance || minSquareDistance === null) {
                minSquareDistance = squareDistance;
                // cancel closestIndex
                closestIndex = null;
                mainArrayIndex = mainIndex;
                subArrayIndex = subIndex;
              }
            });
          });

          const distanceCheck = minSquareDistance;
          if (distanceCheck > 10) {
            self.selectedLine = {};
            self.selectedArrayLinesIndex = null;
            self.selectedArrayLinesToggle = false;
          }
```

Thank you for your time and just want to make sure I understand how to analyze.  Also are there ways to improve situations like this?

Comment: not sure but perhaps this is leaning towards CodeReview?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is right, and no, you can't really optimize that.

Comment: Great!  Thank you for your replies

Comment: `if (index === self.selectedArrayLinesIndex)` should point to an obvious optimisation potential…

Answer (score 2):

From another point of view:

The innards of the double-for loop is a small number of things.

1. `line.move` is probably the most costly (in speed) -- but it is out of your control.
2. That big if(||...); see below
3. All the rest -- relatively insignificant.

Let's optimize that `if`:

```
var x = min(x1, x2) + xdiff;
var y = min(y1, y2) + ydiff;
if ( x < 0 || x > 800 ||
     y < 0 || y > 600 )
```

Similar in code space; a lot faster in speed.

Now, from another point of view...  What is the goal?  To shift a bunch of lines on the screen until any *one* hits an edge?  If that is your focus, then consider this approach:

1. Find the leftmost line -- O(N^2)
2. Compute how many iterations until it hits. -- O(1)
3. Repeat 1&2 for rightmost, topmost, and bottommost.
4. Take min of the above iteration counts. -- O(1)
5. Iterate that many times *without* checking for bumping the edge.

In a sense, that is turning the problem (and the code) "inside out".

Instead of having a 2D array of arrays, you should probably think of it as a 1D array of lines.  I don't see anything that depends on 2D.

Comment: This is a very good explanation and made me think for sure.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about textbook big O, which means the worst case possible, you cannot improve it. But from a practical perspective, yes it can be done. You can change the position of your `if` conditional.

```
(index === self.selectedArrayLinesIndex) // from first function
```

is completely irrelevant to any logic inside your anonymous function in your `beforeEach`. You shouldn't need to loop at all if it fails that condition.

```
if (index === self.selectedArrayLinesIndex) {
  arr.forEach((line) => { // swapped positions
```

Based on the name, I'm quite sure `line.move(xDiff, yDiff)` is your true bottleneck.

Also, if you're looking to split hairs, `for` loops are faster than `beforeEach`